# Debug won't work all of the sudden

Tags: android

A few days ago I just typed android:debuggalbe="true into my manifest and plugged in my phone, when I ran the app it automatically ran on the phone. Im using a mac if that information has anything to do with it, now nothing happens it won't recognize the phone, I enabled usb debugging on the phone.  Is there any way to see if it is even registering? I am really getting angry at this because I've done everything the exact way it says to on the developer website and nothing works.

Comment: what `adb devices` command shows you?

Answer (score 0):

1. check your log filter.
2. Open eclipse android devices view(windows > show view > devices),and click any process in your device;
3. reBoot your phone.

Comment: Ok, I did these things and it shows the phone htc... online, in devices. But it still won't show up at all when I run my app, or try and change what the default emulator is.  Yesterday I just plugged the phone in and it asked me what I wanted to run as with the htc on the list now I only see it under devices and I can't find it anywhere when I try and run.

Comment: well never mind I have no characters left so ill just quit trying this is so stupid I know its one tiny thing wrong that it just assumes you know on the developer site as usual with problems i have.